# Retraining CNN Model

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, conv-neural-network

I have created my CNN model which takes data from training set folder and from test set folder, now in each training set folder I have added some sub folders to both the folders. I have trained my model on given data but what if I want to expand the learning of my model? If I add another folder in my training set and in test test, I have to retrain my model completely.

**How can i save time in this situation?**

Suppose I have already added 5 folders in training set and in test test and trained it on those and then I wish to expand data and add two new folders of data into training and test set, I have to re-run my model again completely and retrain it again.

**Can anyone enlighten me on this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the trained model as initialization for the new model and **fine-tune** it using the new data. This is commonly used practice to save time. That means:

1. you save the weights of the model trained on the old data
2. you add new training data
3. you create new model and load the weights from the old one
4. you train the model like you would normally

Once you are confident that your setup works great and you have all the data that you want, you can train from scratch.

Comment: But wouldn't it overwrite what it had learned from old data??? Since old data and new data would be in same folder?

Comment: Let's say the old model works well on the old data. Now you fine-tune this model on both the old and new data together, which ensures that it keeps good performance on the old, but also adapts to recognize the new. When this training is done, you can save the weights into a different file, making sure nothing is overwritten.